# Unity 3D Spell casting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system

I'm having trouble implementing working spells in Unity 3D 5.3.5. I have an empty game object which is the parent of the ability, it contains only a script called Spell and also a child which is the particle system. For testing purposes I left it in the resource folder so I can easily instantiate it like this

```
GameObject castedSpell = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Fireball"), transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

- `transform` refers to the current Player object's `transform`

However it is spawning in the ground which can be fixed by moving the y axis from the transform, but this doesn't sounds like a good idea also sometimes the particles will collide with the player, and I want to instantiate the spell towards a crosshair in the middle of the screen : http://prntscr.com/bx91op

The crosshair works exactly like the one in Tera online - reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jcg4o8IVwlw

I do have a copy of this crosshair but I still dont know how to instantiate the spell towards it. I also need to do some damaging, etc. when the spell collides. I saw that the particle system has a collision property and also an event trigger `private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)` but this doesn't seem to work at all when I attached that to the main particle object http://prntscr.com/bx9356. My player object has the layer tag of `PlayArea`, when I set the collision property to not collide with this specific tag nothing changes it will still explode inside the player.

So a short summary of my questions :

1. How to instantiate properly a spell ?
2. How to rotate it and send it in direction to the crosshair on the screen ?
3. How to prevent collision with specific objects ?
4. How to check when a collision occurs ?

Comment: If you use the player as starting position, it's logical that the spell might start at the bottom. This depends on the origin of the player object. Usually you use an empty gameobject that acts as start position and that is positioned properly (e.g. at the front of a gun). In you case this might be at the hand of the player. For preventing collision with certain objects you can use various things, e.g. layers or tags. And collision can be detected with functions like `OnCollisionEnter`.

Comment: For the direction I would suggest something like `transform.position.forward` where transform refers to the player. Rotation should be the players rotation accordingly.

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ShootingWeaponScript

Comment: Gunnar has explained everything.  Don't forget one of the most common things in games is, when you spawn something, you "try it a few times" until you find a point that is empty.  Please note that general questions like this are for **gamedev.com**, this site is for code questions

Comment: How can you do that without code again ? @JoeBlow

Comment: I've no idea what you're saying, but this sort of question is for **gamedev.com**.  you're asking for a general **technique** how to do something in a video game (which is a question for gamedev.com).  further, there are 100s of QA on the many questions you ask - you need only search

Comment: @GunnarB. but this wont spawn spells where the crosshair is looking

Comment: Well, you will have some information for actually displaying the crosshair in a certain direction according to the camera (probably). So you should be able to get the direction/rotation from there.

Answer (score 1):

Since most of your question has already been answered in the comments I'll only address nr. 2:

To make a GameObject target a specific point you can use the [transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function.

For determining said target point the best option is propably to do a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from your camera/crosshair into your scene. The first point hit by the ray can then be used as target point for your spell. (Just be careful about walls or objects between your camera and character...)